# How do I use the three-digit separator in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want the digit separator to be applied when the user enters the number, but without the separator when inserted into the database. please guide. Thank you

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MablaghHazineh, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

Comment: What on earth is a "3 digit separator"? Do you mean _digit grouping_? That depends entirely on the user's web-browser and support for customizing the appearance of `<input` elements. FWIW, if you're using numbers then you should use `<input type="number"` and not `<input type="text">` (which is what `TextBoxFor` renders).

Comment: Exactly, I mean the three-digit separator, for example: 876,258,753